# cabal glib installation error

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, glib

I try install install glib via cabal

```
evgeny@virtuos:~$ cabal install glib-0.13.0.7
Resolving dependencies...
Failed to install glib-0.13.0.7
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
glib-0.13.0.7 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
user error (The package 'glib' requires Cabal library version -any && >=1.18
but no suitable version is installed.)
evgeny@virtuos:~$ cabal --version 
cabal-install version 1.20.0.3
using version 1.20.0.2 of the Cabal library
```

what's wrong?
OS: Ubuntu 14.10
Cabal 1.20.0.3
GHC: 7.6.3

Comment: What does `ghc-pkg list Cabal` say?

Answer (score 2):

Run `cabal install cabal-install`. Daniel Wagner's suggestion will most likely provide different results than `cabal --version`.